# Market Downloads, GTalk and GMail notifications fail when on company VPN

Tags: vpn

I've noticed that when I login over WIFI to my company VPN the following problems occur:

1. GTalk does not login.
2. No GMail notifications received.
3. I can access the Android Market but when I attempt to download an application it fails.

All these work ok on my home WIFI and 3G connections.
Does anyone have any idea what would cause this?
What protocols/ports do these services use and is it possible to edit them?

Comment: Ask your company's administrator? They surely should know better than some strangers in the internet if your company blocks some services.

Comment: I agree, it's like some ports being blocked.

Comment: Happy to ask them but wasn't sure what to ask. IE: what protocols/ports do these services use? Is it possible to change them? I've updated the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think GTalk uses port 5228, and the notifications and Market downloads both use the GTalk protocol internally.

Comment: Found this on the google help. Seems like it is ports 5222 and 443.
http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27930